Mount Azure file share to Azure app service
I am trying to mount an Azure file share on Azure app service.
The app service is Windows based (not a container) and it is running .NET.
I have checked the network connectivity, the app is vnet integrated and it is added in allowed entries on the storage account.
I have also tried to reach the storage account with tcpping and it's working as expected.
I mounted the file share using Azure portal.
Running az webapp config storage-account list' lists the fileshare, however the state is "NotValidated".

Have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1264614/how-to-fix-state-notvalidated-in-result-of-az-weba?cid=kerryherger

I tired all of these and it doesnt seem to fix the issue.
Another hint though, when i try to cd to the mount directory from the app service I get "Access denied" error.

For accessing Azure file share from webapp you need to configure nsg in VNet and allow required ports

Just FYI, I also have the same problem, but with Linux .NET Function Apps.  I can create a Function App without VNet integration and use az webapp config storage-account add with no problems.  The same with a VNet-integrated Function App results in "NotValidated".  I have added a NSG to the Function App's subnet allowing inbound and outbound to EVERY port just to rule that out, and still no joy.  SSHing onto the Function App and using nc, I can see that ports 80 and 445 are both open to the Storage Account.  The Storage Account is open to all public and network traffic.

There is no VNet firewall configured.  Also running AzFileDiagnostics on the Function App host seems to suggest that everything is healthy in terms of ports and configuration, but no joy unfortunately.  I am using UK West, if that makes any difference :)  Interestingly, slightly different from OP's behaviour, I don't have any mounted folder on the Function App host.  Thanks for any help!

A quick update - I have now successfully started to mount the file shares onto VNet-integrated Linux Function Apps.  I have no idea what change I've made which has made this spring to life, but I'm working on it!  The Azure CLI still says "NotValidated" but I can now successfully list files in the file share when SSHed onto the Function host.

Update from my side, completely removing restrictions from the Storage account resolved the issue. However, that is obviously not a permanent solution. Not sure what else should be done other than whitelisging the VNET where the app service is integrated. The VNET itself has no NSGs.

Guess I should've read the docs a little better. A few points:

Storage firewall is supported only through private endpoints and service endpoints (when VNET integration is used).
With VNET integration on your app, the mounted drive uses an RFC1918 IP address and not an IP address from your VNET

So I will have to proceed with a private endpoint.

Ok, so final update.
It seems that if the app service is vnet integrated, and you have access restrictions on the Storage account, it is not just enough to add the vnet to the whitelist on the Storage account.
Firstly, you need to add a Storage account service endpoint in the subnet where your app service is.
Then you need to add the following app setting on your app service:
WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET = 1
